# SSLHandshakeException trying to connect to a server over SSL

Tags: java, linux, spring, ssl, https

I'm trying to make a GET request from a Java/Spring 4 Application to a resource on a remote server over SSL.
Say the resource is:

https://remote-app/foo.pdf

my application uses https://github.com/square/okhttp as an HTTP client to do the operation.

Unfortuanatelly it is throwing an exception on this resources; but surprisingly succeeds on other resources that are exposed over SSL on other servers.

Here is the exception that I'm getting:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2023) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1125) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectTls(SocketConnector.java:103) ~[okhttp-2.4.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:143) ~[okhttp-2.4.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:185) ~[okhttp-2.4.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128) ~[okhttp-2.4.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:341) ~[okhttp-2.4.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330) ~[okhttp-2.4.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248) ~[okhttp-2.4.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:273) ~[okhttp-2.4.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:230) ~[okhttp-2.4.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:201) ~[okhttp-2.4.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:81) ~[okhttp-2.4.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.org.package.util.Utils.getUrlResponse(MyUtils.java:54) ~[app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
    at com.org.package.service.impl.MyApp.uploadUrl(MyApp.java:303) [app.jar!/:na]
    at com.org.package.service.impl.MyApp.uploadResource(MyApp.java:135) [app.jar!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) [spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) [spring-tx-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) [spring-tx-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) [spring-tx-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) [spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy155.uploadR(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at com.org.myprocess.receiveRequest(Processor.java:42) [app.jar!/:na]
    at com.org.myprocess$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e05dc31.invoke(<generated>) [spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) [spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717) [spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) [spring-tx-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) [spring-tx-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) [spring-tx-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653) [spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at com.org.myprocess$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d16a8116.receiveRequest(<generated>) [spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:185) [spring-messaging-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) [spring-messaging-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.AbstractMethodMessageHandler.handleMatch(AbstractMethodMessageHandler.java:447) [spring-messaging-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.AbstractMethodMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMethodMessageHandler.java:408) [spring-messaging-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.AbstractMethodMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMethodMessageHandler.java:346) [spring-messaging-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.executeMessage(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:160) [spring-cloud-aws-messaging-1.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$MessageExecutor.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:226) [spring-cloud-aws-messaging-1.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$SignalExecutingRunnable.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:250) [spring-cloud-aws-messaging-1.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.0.3.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_51]
    Suppressed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
        ... 60 common frames omitted
```

I tried curl from the machine on which my app is deployed:

```
curl -v https://www.remote-app/foo.pdf
```

Response>>>

```
 Trying 121.1.102.15...
    * Connected to www.remote-app (121.1.102.15) port 443 (#0)
    * Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
    *   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
      CApath: none
    * NSS error -12286 (SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP)
    * Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s).
    * Closing connection 0
    curl: (35) Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s).
```

But then I tried passing the cipher algorithm to use and it works:

```
curl -v --cipher ecdhe_rsa_aes_128_gcm_sha_256 https://www.remote-app/foo.pdf
```

Response>>>

```
Trying 121.1.102.15...
200 OK...
Content...
Content...
```

Now my question is how can I make my app connect to different SSL servers that might have different ssl configuration. Because the app connects to most resources over ssl but not all.

Or how can I support more cipher suites that could be used by different server? (assuming that's the right issue)

Comment: It looks like that ought to be supported https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/CipherSuite.java#L224, but then the master branch doesn't appear to have a `com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector` class. What version of okhttp are you using?

Comment: @ptomli  okhttp:2.4.0

Comment: Looks like okHttp released 2.5.0 - http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp/okhttp  but I'm not sure if it's okHttp that's the point of failure? I'll try upgrading just incase. Tho the encription suite file was there from 2014.

Comment: Is your remote server publicly accessible?  Have you tried running SSLLabs analysis on it?  Sounds like it might not be enumerating its supported ciphers properly if other sites work but it doesn't (especially with your curl test results).

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Comment: Yes the site is publicly accessible. Browsers could see the pdf file that i'm trying to access programmatically. I've been using ssllabs.com to see that the remote server supports 4 ciphers. Here are the ciphers: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030)   ECDH 256 bits (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS  256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc028)   ECDH 256 bits (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS 256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)   ECDH 256 bits (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS  128
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc027)   ECDH 256 bits (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS

Comment: upgrading to the latest okhttp 2.5.0 didn't help

Comment: I was initially thinking this was a problem with the http client (=okhttp) so I replaced okhttp 2.5 with Apache httpComponents to run to the same issue. So I cancelled that hypothesis/possibility. I narrowed the problem to either Java or the Box not supporting the cipher I want. Or some other problem that I don't know about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yay, so I got the solution.**
Java comes with certain ciphers that are disabled by default and some enabled. Here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html
Surprisingly all the 4 ciphers that I mentioned above are in the "enabled-by-default" table.
But below the list of ciphers they mentioned:

> Cipher suites that use Elliptic Curve Cryptography (ECDSA, ECDH,
>   ECDHE, ECDH_anon) require a JCE cryptographic provider that meets the
>   following requirements: a... b... c...

Searching for JAVA JCE provider will lead you to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html

Download the zip file and you'll get two jar files inside 
local_policy.jar
us_export_policy.jar

place those two jar files in the security folder inside ur jre
jdk1.8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/

Cheers!